# Issue using BeautifulSoup and reading target URLs from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Everything works as expected when I'm using a single URL for the URL variable to scrape, but not getting any results when attempting to read links from a csv. Any help is appreciated.

Info about the CSV:

- One column with a header called "Links"
- 300 rows of links with no space, commoa, ; or other charters before/after the links
- One link in each row

```
    import requests  # required to make request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # required to parse html
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    
    with open("urls.csv") as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        for link in reader:
            res = requests.get(link['Links'])
            #print(res.url)
    url = res
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    email_elm0 = soup.find_all(class_= "app-support-list__item")[0].text.strip()
    email_elm1 = soup.find_all(class_= "app-support-list__item")[1].text.strip()
    email_elm2 = soup.find_all(class_= "app-support-list__item")[2].text.strip()
    email_elm3 = soup.find_all(class_= "app-support-list__item")[3].text.strip()
    
    final_email_elm = (email_elm0,email_elm1,email_elm2,email_elm3)
    
    
    print(final_email_elm)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(final_email_elm)
    
    #getting an output in csv format for the dataframe we created
    #df.to_csv('draft_part2_scrape.csv')
```

Comment: Since you already importing pandas, try reading the csv with `df = pd.read_csv()`.  This will allow you to have easily a list of the links with `df['Links']`. The just iterate. Would this work for you?

Comment: @Phineas thanks. I'm able to read the links with `df = pd.read_csv()` but not able to create a soup from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this part of the code:

```py
with open("urls.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for link in reader:
        res = requests.get(link['Links'])
...
```

After the loop is executed, `res` will have the last link. So, this program will only **scrape** the last link.

To solve this problem, store all the links in a list and iterate that list to **scrape** each of the link. You can store the **scraped** result in a seperate dataframe and concatenate them at the end to store in a single file:

```py
import requests  # required to make request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # required to parse html
import pandas as pd
import csv

links = []
with open("urls.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for link in reader:
        links.append(link['Links'])
        

dfs = []
for url in links:
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    email_elm0 = soup.find_all(class_="app-support-list__item")[0].text.strip()
    email_elm1 = soup.find_all(class_="app-support-list__item")[1].text.strip()
    email_elm2 = soup.find_all(class_="app-support-list__item")[2].text.strip()
    email_elm3 = soup.find_all(class_="app-support-list__item")[3].text.strip()

    final_email_elm = (email_elm0, email_elm1, email_elm2, email_elm3)
    print(final_email_elm)

    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(final_email_elm))


#getting an output in csv format for the dataframe we created
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_csv('draft_part2_scrape.csv')
```

Comment: `line 19, in <module> page = requests.get(url) `
 `line 76, in get return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs) `
 `line 61, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) `
 `line 530, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) `
 `line 637, in send adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url) `
 `line 728, in get_adapter raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url)) `
 `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'Links\n0 `

Comment: @neohex Its because the object named url is not a string but a requests object.... Moosa's code is making two get requests, one on the actual url and one on the outcome of this request...

Comment: @Phineas is it just the matter of changing the URL variable to something else in the for loop? I tried changing it and still getting the error. Sorry, if I'm asking for a lot of hand holding.I'm still a beginner, but testing everything I can.

Comment: @neohex I have edited my answer and updated what @Phineas pointed out. You can copy that code. The only difference is in the first `for` loop. `res = requestslinks.getappend(link['Links'])` this statement is removed and the second statement is updated to `links.append(link['Links'])`

Comment: Thanks. Getting a key error for Links. Trying to debug. `line 10, in <module>
    links.append(link['Links'])
KeyError: 'Links' `